# Crystal Report java library, logon hangs forever

Tags: java, web-services, crystal-reports, business-objects

Our project uses Business Objects for reports.  Our java webapps that launch reports go thruogh a web service we set up to handle the business rules of how we want to launch them.  Works great...with one wrinkle.

BO appears to be massively unreliable.  The thing frequently goes down or fails to come up after a nightly timed restart.  Our Ops team has sort of gotten used to this as a fact of life.

But the part of that which impacts me, on the java team, is our webservice tries to log on to BO, and instead of timing our or erroring like it should, the BO java library hangs forever.  Evidently it is connecting to a half-started BO, and never gives up.

Looking around the internet, it appears that others have experienced this, but none of the things I see suggests how to set a timeout on the logon process so that if it fails, the web service doesn't lock up forever (which in turn can cause our app server to become unstable).

The connection is pretty simple:

```
session = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr().logon(boUserName, boPassword, boServerName, boSecurityType);
```

All I am looking for is some way to make sure that if BO is dead, my webservice doesn't die with it.  A timeout...a way to reliably detect if BO is not started and healthy before trying to logon....something.  Our BO "experts" don't seem to think there is anything they can do about BO's instability and they know even less about the java library.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Java SDK does not detail how to define a timeout when calling `logon`. I can only assume that this means it falls back on a default network connection timeout.

However, if a connection is made but the SDK doesn't receive the required information (and keeps waiting for an answer), a network timeout will never be reached as this is an application issue, not a network issue.

Therefore, the only thorough solution would be to **deal with the instabilities** in your BusinessObjects platform (for which you should create a separate question and describe the issue in more detail).

If this is not an option, an alternative could be to **launch the connection attempt in a separate thread** and implement a timeout yourself, killing the thread when the predefined timeout is reached and optionally retrying the connection attempt several times.

Keep in mind though that while the initial logon might be successful, the instabilities described in your question could cause other issues (e.g. a different SDK call could remain hanging forever due to the same issue that caused your `logon` call to hang).

Again, the only good solution is to look at the **root cause of your platform instabilities**.

Comment: Thanks, the thread idea is a good one, and we'll definitely consider that.  We know that the instabilities come when our nightly database backup runs a little long, and BO spazzes out over it.  Our ops guys seem content to just force reboots on a schedule.  They seem uninterested in pursuing it beyond that.  A more graceful fail from our app, so that the contagion is contained is as much solution as I can force.